# TFS Users Incorrect

Tags: azure-devops

I have just started working with a company that uses VS Team Services. They set me up with a user account and then pulled the code base to my local PC. Whenever I go to check-out/check-in a file, the username that appears is that of the administrator, not me. I'm not at all familiar with team services because I used git previously. I tried removing the existing workspace and then re-created it, making sure VS showed my username on the team connection settings, but this didn't  change anything. I'm using VS 2010 currently.

Here are some screenshots

[Checkout not me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x9ZG9.png)
 And 
[TFS Connection showing me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPKz2.png)

Comment: Thanks for the downvote. Really. I'm new to stack and need to learn how to ask for help the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure your personal account has been added to the team project you are working on. Check [Add users to a team project](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/add-users).

Then, go to Team Explorer as the screenshot below, click **Manage Connections** or **Select Team Projects** (depends on the VS version), select the VSTS you are using, and click **Switch User** to use your own account:

[image]

Comment: We had verified the things you mentioned. I added screenshots to show what we see.

Comment: When you check-out/check-in a file, which user name will you see in Source Control Explorer?

Comment: When I manually check out files through source control explorer it is showing my user. Files that I open via the solution explorer get automatically checked out to the admins user.

Comment: I have also noticed that some files checkout as soon as I open them while others I have to make an edit before they checkout. Regardless of when it occurs, if it is from solution explorer it goes to the admin, not me.

Comment: We figured it out. Thank you